# How to reveal string one letter at a time?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm learning from a book, and this is the assignment question i'm working on:
 Create an app that asks for the users name and then displays the name down the side of      the screen, one letter at a time.

- Clarify what i'm trying trying to do: Have users name fade in one at a time vertically. Example: **Adam**  "*A*" would appear after 1 second , "*d*" would appear after 3 seconds under the displayed *A*, "*a*" would appear after 5 seconds under the displayed *d*, "*m*" would appear after 7 seconds under the displayed *a*. The visuals would have a sort of domino effect.When they appear they would stay displayed on screen.

So far i'm able to get the user's name and display it side ways. Have it fade it in within 2 seconds. I'm stuck on how to get the letters to fade in one letter at a time.

```
function submit ()  
print( "connect" )
userName = userNameField.text
display_userName = display.newText( userName, display.contentWidth-20, display.contentHeight/2 )
    display_userName.rotation = 90
    display_userName.alpha = 0

userNameField: removeSelf( )
greeting:removeSelf( )
submitButton:removeSelf( )

transition.fadeIn( display_userName, {time = 2000} )
```

Please let me know if you need to see more of my code.

Comment: Not clear what that means "displays the name down the side of the screen, one letter at a time". Does it mean that you only see a box that is large enough for one letter, and you see each letter in it for a couple seconds? Maybe you can draw it and insert image in your question?

Comment: I hope that "Clarify" bullet point help illustrate what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a simple way as below:

```
local myString = "Adam"  -- Create your string
local positionCount = 0     -- initialize a variable to determine letter position

local function displayData()
  positionCount = positionCount + 1
  if(positionCount<=string.len(myString))then
    -- if positionCount is less than or equal to letters in 'myString'
    local letter = string.sub(myString, positionCount, positionCount) -- get the current letter
    local letterLabel = display.newText(letter,20,20*positionCount,nil,20) -- place the letter
    letterLabel.alpha = 0;
    -- display the label and update the function after the completion of transition
    transition.to(letterLabel,{time=1000,alpha=1,onComplete=displayData})
  end
end
displayData()
```

Keep Coding.................... :)

Comment: How do I remove usernamefield? When I use removeSelf (), I get a result of only the first letter of the person's name fading in.

Comment: What do you mean by removing usernamefield. Please clarify. That was not included in the question. Otherwise ask it as a new question. So why unaccepted..?

Comment: I've made a new question as suggested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726814/how-to-hide-native-newtextfield-after-clicking-submit . I hope that clears the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet for storing every character in a table.
Initialise a variable:

```
check =0;
```

Here splitWord is an table to store each character of string. and variable "yourStringForOneLetter" is your string variable for splitting. "string.sub" will split string into words using for loop.

```
 if(check==wordSize) then
   check=1
 end

 local wordSize = string.len(yourStringForOneLetter)
 splitWord = {}

 for i=check, check do            
   splitWord[i] = string.sub(yourStringForOneLetter, i, i)    
   check= check +1;
 end
```