# How to hide native.newTextField after clicking submit?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying trying to have users name fade in one letter at a time vertically. Example: Adam "A" would appear after 1 second , "d" would appear after 3 seconds under the displayed A, "a" would appear after 5 seconds under the displayed d, "m" would appear after 7 seconds under the displayed a. The visuals would have a sort of domino effect.When they appear they would stay displayed on screen.

When if I comment out userNameField:removeSelf () then the code works fine. I get the effect I want, but the problem is that I still have the userNamefield showing.

Please let me know if you need to see more code.

```
local greeting = display.newText( "Greetings, enter your name",0,0,native.systemFont, 20 )
greeting.x = display.contentWidth/2
greeting.y = 100

local submitButton = display.newImage( "submit.png"  ,display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight - 50 )

local userNameField = native.newTextField( display.contentWidth * 0.5 , 150, 250, 45)
userNameField.inputtype = "defualt"


local incrementor = 0
function showNameLetters()

userNameField:removeSelf( )
if incrementor <= string.len ("userNameField.text") then
    incrementor = incrementor + 1
    personLetters = string.sub (userNameField.text, incrementor,incrementor)
    display_personLetters = display.newText (personLetters, 290,30*incrementor, native.systemFont, 30)
        display_personLetters.alpha = 0
    transition.to(display_personLetters,{time = 3000, alpha = 1, onComplete = showNameLetters})
end
end
```

**Update:**

I've found a solution to my problem, by adding userNameField.isVisible = false in my function.

I've also found something very weird, and wish to have someone explain why this happens. If I add greeting:removeSelf() and submitButton:removeSelf() (I've commented them out in my code below to show you where I put them for testing). I get weird result of only the first letter fading in. If i set greeting.isVisible = false and submitButton.isVisible = false. The code works fine.

I'm so confused why object:removeSelf() wouldn't work. Can someone please clear this up for me.

That is, if I replace the following line:

```
userNameField:removeSelf( )
```

with:

```
userNameField.isVisible = false
```

then the app works fine. Please suggest me why/ any solution for the question. THanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're calling the **showNameLetters** multiple times, this means that you're removing the native text field more than once. Nil it and check for nil before removing it like this:

```
if userNameField ~= nil then
 userNameField:removeSelf()
 userNameField = nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows that you are using data from userNameField after removing it (in the line below):

```
personLetters = string.sub (userNameField.text, incrementor,incrementor)
```

As well as you are calling `object:removeSelf()` again and again without checking its existance (as mentioned by hades2510). So before removing `userNameField`, check for it's existance:

```
if userNameField ~= nil then
 userNameField:removeSelf()
 userNameField = nil
end
```

And you won't get `userNameField.text` while userNameField is nil. So use a temporary variable to hold the previous `userNameField.text` and get the saved data from that variable when needed.

**Extra note:** Are you sure, you have to check the length of the text `"userNameField.text"` in the following line, or the variable `userNameField.text`? If you have to use the data from the text field, then this will also matter.

```
if incrementor <= string.len ("userNameField.text") then
  ........
end
```

Keep coding....................... :)